# Unpacking kernel-source rpm off-system (OpenSuse)?

Tags: linux-kernel, source, rpm, opensuse

I'm using OpenSuse 11.2 from a LiveUSB USB flash/stick, which arguably has not much place on it. I need to get the Linux sources for this version of OpenSuse, as they are needed to build a driver for an application I'm using. I have plenty of disk space on an attached hard-drive, so I'd like to "install" the sources there (*note that on 11.2, `zypper --download-only` will by default [download to /var/cache/zypp/packages](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/451117-zypper-download-only-comand.html), which crashes my LiveUSB setup*).

So, I do the following:

```
> cd /media/myhdrive/
> wget http://download.opensuse.org/update/11.2/rpm/src/kernel-source-2.6.31.14-0.8.1.src.rpm

> mkdir kernel-source-2.6.31.14
> cd kernel-source-2.6.31.14/
> rpm2cpio ../kernel-source-2.6.31.14-0.8.1.src.rpm | cpio -idmv --no-absolute-filenames

> ls
arch-symbols              kernel-source.rpmlintrc   patches.kabi.tar.bz2
built-in-where            kernel-source.spec        patches.kernel.org.tar.bz2
check-for-config-changes  kernel-source.spec.in     patches.rpmify.tar.bz2
check-supported-list      kernel-spec-macros        patches.rt.tar.bz2
compute-PATCHVERSION.sh   kernel-syms.spec.in       patches.staging.tar.bz2
....
```

... and there is a bunch of `*.tar.gz` files (patches) - and not anything resembling C source files. I'm guessing there is a script/command I should apply now to unpack the source tree, but I have no idea what it - I've seen `rpmbuild -bb ...` [here](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/other-forums/development/open-build-service-obs/440303-problem-kernel-source-2-6-34-9-3-src-rpm.html), but I guess that will build yet another `.rpm` - while I want the actual sources unpacked (and that at a location I specify - not in `/usr/src` or anywhere on root filesystem).

Any ideas what I should do now?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

EDIT: via [Building a custom kernel - FedoraProject](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel#Prepare_the_Kernel_Source_Tree), trying `rpmbuild -bp`, but it fails:

```
# man rpmbuild:
# -bp    Executes the "%prep" stage from the spec file.  Normally  this  involves
unpacking the sources and applying any patches.

> mkdir src
> rpmbuild --buildroot=$(pwd)/src/ -bp --target=$(uname -m) kernel-source.spec
Building target platforms: i686
Building for target i686
error: Unable to open /usr/src/packages/SOURCES/kernel-spec-macros: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Use the `-bc` switch of `rpmbuild`:

> -bc     Do  the "%build" stage from the spec file (after doing the %prep stage).
>             This generally involves the equivalent of a "make".

... since `-bp` will just unpack the "sources" related to the .rpm, but will not "make" them - which involves applying the specific SUSE patches... My attempt to use `rpmbuild -bp` is left below for reference - not that it, on its own, doesn't even extract the linux sources. Below is the log of using `rpmbuild -bc`, which both unpacks vanilla sources and applies patches to them (*which can be seen from the terminal log, which has been left out here; note also that the patched sources will be in "`BUILDROOT`"*):

```
> mkdir -p rpmbuild/{BUILD,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
> echo "%_topdir $(pwd)/rpmbuild" > ~/.rpmmacros
> rpm -i ../kernel-source-2.6.31.14-0.8.1.src.rpm

> ls rpmbuild/*
rpmbuild/BUILD:

rpmbuild/RPMS:

rpmbuild/SOURCES:
arch-symbols              kernel-source.rpmlintrc   patches.kernel.org.tar.bz2
built-in-where            kernel-source.spec.in     patches.rpmify.tar.bz2
...

> cd rpmbuild/SPECS

> rm -rf ../BUILD/*
> rpmbuild -bc --target=`uname -m` kernel-source.spec 2>&1

> ls ../BUILDROOT/
kernel-source-2.6.31.14-0.8.1.i386

> ls ../BUILD
kernel-source-2.6.31.14

> ls -la ../BUILDROOT/kernel-source-2.6.31.14-0.8.1.i386/usr/src/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 linux users 4096 2011-11-11 20:55 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 linux users 4096 2011-11-11 20:54 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 linux users    5 2011-11-11 20:54 linux -> linux
drwxr-xr-x 24 linux users 4096 2011-11-11 20:56 linux-2.6.31.14-0.8.1
drwxr-xr-x 23 linux users 4096 2011-11-11 20:55 linux-2.6.31.14-0.8.1-vanilla

> ls ../BUILDROOT/kernel-source-2.6.31.14-0.8.1.i386/usr/src/linux-2.6.31.14-0.8.1
arch     crypto         fs       Kbuild  MAINTAINERS  README          security  virt
block    Documentation  include  kdb     Makefile     REPORTING-BUGS  sound
....
```

---

Ok, this turned out to be quite convoluted (given I still don't know the proper way to do this), but the post [How to compile custom kernel on Centos/Xen or optimize CS:S server](http://tech-stuff.org/how-to-compile-custom-kernel-on-centosxen-or-optimize-css-server/) showed the way. Following that post, I did this ( *still in the `kernel-source-2.6.31.14/`
 directory as in the OP* ):

```
> mkdir -p rpmbuild/{BUILD,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
> echo "%_topdir $(pwd)/rpmbuild" > ~/.rpmmacros
> rpm -i ../kernel-source-2.6.31.14-0.8.1.src.rpm

> ls rpmbuild/*
rpmbuild/BUILD:

rpmbuild/RPMS:

rpmbuild/SOURCES:
arch-symbols              kernel-source.rpmlintrc   patches.kernel.org.tar.bz2
built-in-where            kernel-source.spec.in     patches.rpmify.tar.bz2
...

> cd rpmbuild/SPECS

> rpmbuild -bp --target=`uname -m` kernel-source.spec
Building target platforms: i686
Building for target i686
error: Failed build dependencies:
        fdupes is needed by kernel-source-2.6.31.14-0.8.1.src

> sudo zypper install fdupes

> rpmbuild -bp --target=`uname -m` kernel-source.spec
Building target platforms: i686
Building for target i686
Executing(%prep): /bin/bash -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.4uWZo1
+ umask 022
+ cd /path/to/kernel-source-2.6.31.14/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ '[' -e /path/to/kernel-source-2.6.31.14/rpmbuild/SOURCES/linux-2.6.31.tar.bz2 ']'
+ echo 'Symbol(s): '
Symbol(s):
+ cd /path/to/kernel-source-2.6.31.14/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf kernel-source-2.6.31.14
+ /bin/mkdir -p kernel-source-2.6.31.14
+ cd kernel-source-2.6.31.14
+ /usr/bin/bzip2 -dc /path/to/kernel-source-2.6.31.14/rpmbuild/SOURCES/config.tar.bz2
+ /bin/tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ /usr/bin/bzip2 -dc /path/to/kernel-source-2.6.31.14/rpmbuild/SOURCES/patches.arch.tar.bz2
+ /bin/tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ /usr/bin/bzip2 -dc /path/to/kernel-source-2.6.31.14/rpmbuild/SOURCES/patches.drivers.tar.bz2
+ /bin/tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
... [snip] ...
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ exit 0


> ls ../BUILD/kernel-source-2.6.31.14/
config            patches.arch     patches.kabi        patches.rt       patches.trace
patches.addon     patches.drivers  patches.kernel.org  patches.staging  patches.xen
patches.apparmor  patches.fixes    patches.rpmify      patches.suse
....

# ?? no linux sources?
```

... and, surprisingly, after all this, I still couldn't see any linux sources? However, I did notice that `-e /path/to/kernel-source-2.6.31.14/rpmbuild/SOURCES/linux-2.6.31.tar.bz2` in the script above; and guessing that the linux*.tar.bz2 probably didn't get unpacked (there was nothing after the `Symbol(s):` line in the original output for the snippet above); I basically repeated what the `rpmbuild` tmp script did:

```
# done previously
> # cd ./rpmbuild/SPECS/ 
> # rpmbuild -bp --target=`uname -m` kernel-source.spec 2>&1  


> cd ../..
> cd ./rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-source-2.6.31.14/
> /usr/bin/bzip2 -dc ../../../rpmbuild/SOURCES/linux-2.6.31.tar.bz2  | /bin/tar -xf -

> ls               # linux-2.6.31 directory gets created
> ls linux-2.6.31/
arch     crypto         fs       Kbuild       Makefile  REPORTING-BUGS  sound
block    Documentation  include  kernel       mm        samples         tools
...
```

Well.. finally, those *are* linux source files I can recognize :)

However, those are still, seemingly, the "vanilla" 'unpatched' sources - I guess there is a command that does all this along with patching, but I'm at loss as to what it is... Anyways, hope this may also help others a bit - cheers!